# how can I pass 10 arguments in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, parameter-passing, mips, procedure, subroutine

```
.data

.text
main:  
        # 5 parameters  
        li $s0, 2  
        li $s1, 3  
        li $s2, 5  
        li $s3, 10  
        li $s4, 20 

        addi $sp, $sp, -20 # 5 Words are 5 * 4 bytes  
        sw $s0, 0($sp)  
        sw $s1, 4($sp)  
        sw $s2, 8($sp)  
        sw $s3, 16($sp)  
        sw $s4, 20($sp)  

        jal addFiveNumbers  

        # free stack  
        addi $sp, $sp, 20  

        # print the result in $v0  
        move $a0, $v0
        li $v0, 1
        syscall

    # terminate program
    li $v0, 10
        syscall

addFiveNumbers:  

    lw $t0, 0($sp)  
    lw $t1, 4($sp)  
    lw $t2, 8($sp)  
    lw $t3, 16($sp)  
    lw $t4, 20($sp)  

    add $v0, $t0, $t1  
    add $v0, $v0, $t2  
    add $v0, $v0, $t3  
    add $v0, $v0, $t4  
    jr $ra
```

I took this program [from here](http://davidlovesprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/09/functions-in-mips.html).

Suppose, I want to add, say, 10 values.

Since there are only eight **$s** registers, how can I pass 10 arguments?

Comment: _"there are only eight $s registers"_ There are 32 registers in total (28 if you exclude `$zero`, `$v0`, `$sp` and `$ra`) and there's nothing saying you have to limit yourself to only the `$s` registers. However, you don't need all those registers you are using: just interleave the `li` and `sw` operations instead of keeping them as separate chunks. That way you only need a single register. Same for the `lw`/`add` operations.

Comment: normally one would use the stack if you run out of registers for parameters.

Comment: @Michael: classic MIPS I actually has 1 load-delay slot: you can't use a load result in the next instruction after a load.  The pipeline doesn't even have interlocks to detect that RAW hazard.  (MIPS II corrected that, since it turned out to be hard for compilers to fill and hurt code density.)  But on an in-order pipeline you still definitely want to software-pipeline your loads at least a couple instructions ahead of the adds that use them.  But yes sure you only *need* 2 registers: one accumulator and one temporary load target.  Of course it's even better to pass some args in regs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code in your question is passing args on the stack, not following the usual C calling convention, and isn't touching any of the `$s` registers, so I don't understand why you think that's relevant at all.  How you use the args inside the callee is obviously limited by the number of available registers in the machine, but that's separate from how you pass them.

---

**The normal MIPS calling convention passes args in `$a0..$a3`**.  `a` stands for argument.  The `$s` registers are call-preserved and not usually used for arg-passing.

**The standard C calling convention on MIPS, like on all normal ISAs, passes args on the stack for args that don't fit in registers.**  (Either because it's a big struct by value, or because there are already 4 register args.)

Look at C compiler output on https://godbolt.org/ for MIPS GCC for a function that passes or receives 10 args to see where it looks for them.  (Maybe store each arg to a `volatile int sink`, so you can compile with optimization and still see it do something.)

---

**You obviously *can* make up any custom calling convention you want if you're writing to the caller and callee yourself in asm**.  If I wanted to pass more than 4 register args, I think the natural choice might be to use `$t0..$t9` and/or `$v0..$v1` after filling up `$a0..$a3`.

But sure, if I wanted to pass some read-only args that the caller won't clobber, `$s` registers would be appropriate for those.  I'm not aware of any C calling conventions for any ISA that have any call-preserved arg-passing registers, but it makes perfect sense in asm.

At that point you're using it with only one caller but maybe from multiple call-sites in the same function, and probably choosing registers based on what's convenient for that caller.  So it's barely an independent function.  But that's fine.